# Enterprise Architect API : How to suppress Login Dialog while login

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am working with Enterprise Architect API and I want to login to an EA Project using its API. I am using the below code for this

```
 Repository.OpenFile2('c:\EAProjects\EASample.eap','admin','password');
```

The problem is when I entered the wrong password in the argument of the function `OpenFile2`, a dialog box appears and it ask for the right password.
***I need to suppress this dialog box.***

I explored the EA API and found two properties `SuppressEADialogs` and `SuppressSecurityDialog` of `Repository`. Setting these properties to True also does not restrict login dialog to come. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think the datastax-enterprise tag is the right tag for this.

Comment: Yes it is.. thanks. I will remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That must be a bug then since the documentation for SuppressSecurityDialog says:

> Suppress the login prompt dialog that appears by default when username
>   and password parameters passed to OpenFile2 are invalid.  For use by
>   external automation clients only.

Best try in the latest version, and if it still doesn't work [report a bug](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/bug_report.html)